# How do I fix a Mac OSX Profile call to missing /usr/local/bin directory?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, user-profiles

Somehow, possibly in-between installing RVM and MacPorts, I get an error message whenever I open up my terminal in Snow Leopard that complains that I have an invalid identifier in my bash export. I've tracked down the culprit to be /usr/local/bin which doesn't seem to exist on my system. Should this worry me? and if not, how do I find out where /usr/local/bin is being called from?

I've looked in .profile, .bashrc, and .bash_profile in my home directory, but I can't seem to find it in any of those files. Where else could it be, or how can I easily find out?

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: I found the culprit... turns out it was nothing to do with /usr/local/bin, as mipadi said. Instead, there was a line in .bash_profile, which was causing the issue:
PATH=$PATH:~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin ; export $PATH;
So I changed this to export PATH=$PATH:~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin and the issue went away. Please comment if this is likely to cause any errors in the future.
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the culprit is the placement of `/usr/local/bin`? When Bash complains of an invalid identifier, it's complaining about the *name* of an exported variable, not the variable's contents (Bash does't care about the contents).

As for `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, and `.bashrc`, if they're not in your home directory, you can just create them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, see my comment for the final solution I settled on.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at the file `/etc/paths` and the files inside the folder `/etc/paths.d` for mention of `/usr/local/bin`? Those files are used by the `path_helper` utility that is invoked from `/etc/profile` to set up different paths for different applications when creating an environment for the logged in user.

Comment: Thanks Ayaz, there's a mention of it in /etc/paths. Should I remove this?

Answer (score 1):

The directory */usr/local/bin*, doesn't exist on a clean install of Mac OS X (or it doesn't contain anything).

So you don't have to worry about this.

Try ***ayaz*** method and it it doesn't work, try looking in */etc/profile* or */etc/bashrc* to see if there are any references to */usr/local/bin*.

Comment: Should I remove the mention of /usr/local/bin from /etc/paths or simply create the bin folder? What binary files would go in here anyway?